# How setup Mail.app IMAP to migrate Mail Server

Tags: mail.app, migration, imap

We changed recently our Hosting provider.
How can we remove the old IMAP account in Apple Mail without loosing any Mails and have them uploaded to the new server including all IMAP folders?

Thanks,
Aldo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

- copy the whole content of the old IMAP account into a local archive
- enable/configure the new IMAP account
- copy the local copy into the new IMAP account

You can probably also do this directly (old IMAP to new IMAP) but I run into IMAP implementations in the past which weren't too stable during batch copying. So keeping a local copy (at least for a short time) is recommended.

If a local copy is not possible due to mailbox size, you can alternatively try to copy old IMAP to new iMAP folder by folder. Be sure to verify each step at least visually.