# Migrating Linux/cyrrus IMAP into Lion server dovecot

Tags: email, server.app, imap

We changing our internal infrastructure and replacing old Linux server with an OS X Lion server. One crucial thing is email - need migrate it without interruption.
Currently we have Linux/Cyrrus, with zilion of stored emails for tens of local users.

Here: [How setup Mail.app IMAP to migrate Mail Server](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33270/how-setup-mail-app-imap-to-migrate-mail-server) is recommennded doing it via local mail client, what is ok for external imap-server for one user, but not practical for the full server-migrate.

What is the recommended way migrate the whole mail-handling from Linux cyrrus/postfix into OS X Lion dovecot? Know anyone some scripts (preferable perl) what can help with the migrating?

My current idea:

- setup DNS, Users, and email handling on the Lion server
- stop the mailserver on the Linux
- migrate all emails (with some script)
- change MX record from Linux to Lion
- start using Lion

Any guides, caveats and/or any helpful comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Cyrus2Dovecot migration tool](http://cyrus2dovecot.sw.fu-berlin.de/) developed by Freie Universität Berlin.

> Cyrus2Dovecot is a full-featured command line tool for converting the e-mails of one or more users from Cyrus format to Dovecot Maildir++ folders. It allows for performing a server transition which is fully transparent to both POP and IMAP users.

And other [migration solutions in the Dovecot wiki](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Migration).

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. Is here any OS X Lion "speciality" about what i need care? Based on you answer i found this: http://www.afp548.com/forum/viewtopic.php?showtopic=25169 . Any other things?

Answer (score 0):

For other people that come here asking this:

Use imapsync, you can get it via macports.

[macports](http://www.macports.org/)

[imapsync home page](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, gbrandt! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.